# How to use regex to reference specific parts?

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python string containing information that I want to pull out using regex.

Example:

```
"The weather is 75 degrees with a humidity of 13%"
```

I want to just pull out the "75" and the "13."  Here is what I've tried so far in Python.

```
import re

str = "The weather is 75 degrees with a humidity of 13%"
m = re.search("The weather is \d+ degrees with a humidity of \d+%", str)
matched = m.group()
```

However, this obviously matches the entire string instead of just the parts I want.  How do I pull out just the numbers that I want?  I've looked into backreferences but it seems to only apply to within the regex pattern itself.

Comment: You may want to read the [doc for `.groups()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) for details/examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = re.search("The weather is (\d+) degrees with a humidity of (\d+)%", str)
matched = m.groups()
```

you need to wrap what you want in parenthesis ...

```
>>> s1 = "The weather is 75 degrees with a humidity of 13%"
>>> m = re.search("The weather is (\d+) degrees with a humidity of (\d+)%", s1)
>>> m.groups()
('75', '13')
```

or just use `findall` to just get the numbers out of any string

```
>>> re.findall("\d+",s1)
['75', '13']
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanted to use named groups?

```
>>> m = re.search("The weather is (?P<temp>\d+) degrees with a humidity of (?P<humidity>\d+)%", s1)
>>> m.group('temp')
'75'
>>> m.group('humidity')
'13'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to extract typed data from text, such as numbers, [`parse`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) is an extremely useful library. In many ways, it is the inverse of string formatting. It takes a pattern, and will do type conversions.

At its simplest, it allows you to avoid worrying about regular expression groups and so forth.

```
>>> s = "The weather is 75 degrees with a humidity of 13%"
>>> parse("The weather is {} degrees with a humidity of {}%", s)
<Result ('75', '13') {}>
```

The `Result` object is pretty easy to work with:

```
>>> r = _
>>> r[0]
'75'
```

We can do better than this by specifying field names and/or type conversions. Here is all we need to do to have the results as integers:

```
>>> parse("The weather is {:d} degrees with a humidity of {:d}%", s)
<Result (75, 13) {}>
```

If we want to use non-index keys, then add field names:

```
>>> parse("The weather is {temp:d} degrees with a humidity of {humidity:d}%", s)
<Result () {'temp': 75, 'humidity': 13}>
>>> r = _
>>> r['temp']
75
```